# FlexLib Windowshade and Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I'm trying to build a collapsible panel in Flex 4. I thought I'd use s/thing like this:

```
<s:Panel
    width="100%">

    <s:controlBarContent>

            <flexlib:WindowShade
                width="100% />

    </s:controlBarContent>

</s:Panel>
```

But that throws an error: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. I grabbed the flexlib zip for flex 4 but I'm still getting that error.

Is there another way to create a collapsible panel in a control bar?

Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the header renderer or header Class for the WindowShade component.
Looking at their code where this exception occurs
 Exception is:

```
TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
at flexlib.containers::WindowShade/createOrReplaceHeaderButton()[...\src\flexlib\containers\WindowShade.as:258]
```

The code that throws exception is this

```
        if(_headerRenderer) {
            _headerButton = _headerRenderer.newInstance() as Button;
        }
        else {
            var headerClass:Class = getStyle("headerClass");
           _headerButton = new headerClass();
        }
```

You need to define either a headerClass or a headerRenderer.
For testing purposes i used

```
    <s:Panel
    width="100%">

    <s:controlBarContent>

        <containers:WindowShade headerClass="mx.controls.Button"
            width="100%" />

    </s:controlBarContent>

</s:Panel>
```

and it works like a charm :)

Have fun and good luck.

Comment: [WindowShade example source](https://github.com/flex-users/flexlib/blob/master/examples/WindowShade/src/WindowShade_Sample.mxml)